# How to populate ModelAndView in HandlerInterceptor for REST service in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, concurrency

I'm building a RESTfull service, using Spring framework.

I need to add custom Cookie to response, after processing request in Controller, based on the response type

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = MY_PROFILE, produces = PRODUCES)
    public @ResponseBody Some myProfile(@RequestBody() A a) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But by the time it reaches my Interceptor

```
public class SomeIntercepter implements HandlerInterceptor {

    ...

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    }

    ...

}
```

**ModelAndView is NULL**, and I can only work with request & response.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way, to make Spring populate **ModelAndView**, with data, without **working** with **HttpServletResponse**, **HttpEntity** or **ModelAndView** explicitly, **leaving Controller intact**? *(I'm not going to use ModelAndView to add a Cookie, I just need to know response Object in Intercepter, and add Cookie to HttpServletResponse.)*
2. I was thinking of solving this, using **ThreadLocal**, but in my understanding, this would brake in case of asynchronous processing. Is there a proven **ThreadLocal** solution for this, that won't break in case I decide to switch to asynchronous processing?

Example Use Case:

Let's say that I'm doing A/B testing, and my UI, renders differently, based on the Cookie in Response.
I would like to have a place where, based on the return object, I could specify this Cookie.

Answer (score 1):

`@ResponseBody` is special in that it tells Spring that the response has already been handled (or rather should be handled with the return value). In this case, there is no need for a `ModelAndView` since there's no view to render. So the MVC stack won't create a `ModelAndView` and none will be made available to the `HandlerInterceptor`. Basically, by the time the `postHandle` is called, the response has already been flushed, you won't be able to write any cookies. And, in any case, `ModelAndView` is not the appropriate place to add cookies. The `HttpServletResponse` is.

Comment: So how can I add a Cookie outside of the Controller? I was not going to use ModelAndView for Cookie, I just need to know response Object in Intercepter, and add a Cookie to HttpServletResponse

Comment: @mavarazy Can you do it before? In the `preHandle`? Can you do it in a `Filter`? Note that you can wrap the `HttpServletResponse` so that it can't flush the response right away (you'd do this in a `Filter`).

Comment: No I can only do it after processing, based on the result. That's why I was thinking of ThreadLocal, so that I could share response in the same Thread, assuming that Intercepter could only run in the same thread.

Comment: @mavarazy That would be a problem because the `HandlerInterceptor` runs much later than the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` that handles the return value (and writes it to the response). One possible solution is to override and register that class as a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` so that it adds your extra Cookie.

Comment: @mavarazy Alternatively, you can create a standalone subtype of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` with a custom annotation which does something similar by wrapping `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

Comment: I was hoping, for less hackier way to do it, but I'll try Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As you use `@ResponseBody`, Spring do not use a model, you have not even declared it in your controller method, and anyway it would not have sense.

But you can allways use request attributes to pass data from a controller to an interceptor and it will be able to use it in its `postHandle` method to decide what to do with response and cookies.